# What do "fwcc", "fwcl", and "fwl" parameters in a URL indicate?

Tags: url, parameters, referrals

I've noticed some site visitors are arriving at www.example.com/?fwcc=1&fwcl=1&fwl=1 .

What does this indicate?

It's difficult to pin down when searching for it as many other URLs have this attached to the end.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just ran into this situation as well. I can't seem to find much online other this thread. Did you find out what caused it?

Comment: Honestly - no not really. I concluded it was either probing with malcious intent, or Tony D's suggestion below about fb, which fits with another comment I saw regarding something similar. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure, but have been seeing these query parameters too. Bit of research on my logs revealed it might by related to facebook shares, likely some parameters added by facebook links for some reason.

Don't think there's anything to worry about

Answer (score 0):

These are the query string variables and are specific to the web site. This is how the server knows some unique parameters about your browsing. [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) sums it up pretty well.

Comment: Thanks, but they're in no-way related to my website and have never used these parameters so would have no idea how these have ended up on the end of the url.

Comment: Um... then may be they are probing your site for query string injection attacks. I don't think you need to be concerned if you are not using query string variables. If you do though, you need to thoroughly check your input. Also, it would help to know the details, such as what is the traffic source(s) that appends criteria to the string. That might help clear it.